# C Server Client FTP. Sometimes when it's a large file I don't read all I send

Tags: c, sockets, ftp

I’m doing a FTP server and client.
I send packages of (size of data (64000 max) + sizeof(struct header)) with a send function which contains a struct header which gives me the size of the data that I need to read with recv function and the file data.
I don’t understand why, when sending a large file, when I read the package, sometimes I don’t read one of the headers so I put the data of the file in my header struct and malloc crashes obviously because the header struct is false and I try to alloc too much.

```
char    *ftp_get_package(int sock, t_header *header)
{
    char    *buff;
    ssize_t ret;

    ret = 0;
    while ((ret += recv(sock, header, sizeof(t_header), 0)) >= 0
            && (size_t)ret < sizeof(t_header))
            ;
    ft_putstr("|"); // DEBUG
    ft_putstr((char*)header); // DEBUG
    ft_putendl("|"); // DEBUG
    ft_putnbr(header->nb_bytes); // DEBUG
    ft_putendl(" <--- get"); // DEBUG
    if (ret != -1)
    {
        if (!(buff = (char*)malloc(header->nb_bytes + 1)))
            ftp_error(NULL, "ERROR: malloc failure\n", 0);
        ret = 0;
        while ((ret += recv(sock, buff + ret, header->nb_bytes, 0)) >= 0
            && (size_t)ret < header->nb_bytes)
            ;
        if (ret > 0)
        {
            buff[ret] = '\0';
            return (buff);
        }
    }
    if (ret == -1)
        ftp_error(NULL, "ERROR: recv failure\n", 0);
    return (NULL);
}

void    ftp_send_package(char *str, int sock, char flag, long size)
{
    t_header    header;
    ssize_t     ret;
    char        *package;
    int         size_header;

    if (size == -1)
        header.nb_bytes = ft_strlen(str);
    else
        header.nb_bytes = size;
    ft_putnbr(header.nb_bytes); // DEBUG
    ft_putendl(" <--- send"); // DEBUG
    header.flag = flag;
    size_header = sizeof(t_header);
    if (!(package = malloc(size_header + header.nb_bytes)))
        ftp_error(NULL, "ERROR: malloc failure !\n", sock);
    ft_memcpy(package, &header, size_header);
    ft_memcpy(package + size_header, str, header.nb_bytes);
    if ((ret = send(sock, package, size_header + header.nb_bytes, 0)) == -1)    
        ftp_error(NULL, "ERROR: send failure\n", sock);
    free(package);
}
```

kiki is file that i use to debug.
Inside there are 'a'*64000 then 'b'*64000 then 'c'*64000 ... 't'*64000
kiki size is 1 280 000

Serveur debug

```
11 <--- get // get -> "mkfile kiki" to create file kiki
||
64000 <--- get
||
64000 <--- get
||
64000 <--- get
||
64000 <--- get
||
64000 <--- get
||
64000 <--- get
||
64000 <--- get
||
64000 <--- get
||
64000 <--- get
||
64000 <--- get
||
64000 <--- get
||
64000 <--- get
|mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm�A| // putstr of header
7885078839350357357 <--- get
serveur(30378,0x7fff7b25c000) malloc: *** 
mach_vm_map(size=7885078839350358016) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
ERROR: malloc failure
```

Client Debug

```
ftp -> put kiki
11 <--- send // send -> "mkfile kiki"
64000 <--- send
64000 <--- send
64000 <--- send
64000 <--- send
64000 <--- send
64000 <--- send
64000 <--- send
64000 <--- send
64000 <--- send
64000 <--- send
64000 <--- send
64000 <--- send
64000 <--- send
64000 <--- send
64000 <--- send
64000 <--- send
64000 <--- send
64000 <--- send
64000 <--- send
64000 <--- send
1 <--- send
0 <--- send
0 <--- send
```

Please ask me questions if you need more details

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Don't tag C++ unless you mean to

Comment: Are you programming in C or C++? Unless you're comparing the two languages, or actually programming in both for the same project (and the problem is related to the interaction between C and C++) then don't add both tags. Only use the language-tag of the programming language you actually use. Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also please read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: MSDN: 'If no error occurs, send returns the total number of bytes sent, which can be less than the number requested to be sent in the len parameter.'   You only check for an error return, not for a 'short send'.  You should have a loop around the send(), similar to the one you use round recv().

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends or `void *` in general. The code contains a lot of flaws and errors. For example you don't check for errors.  That makes tracking down errors problematic, even with a debugger. And  "Please ask me questions if you need more details" is not how this site works. Read [ask].

Comment: You don't need the cast `(size_t)ret` since that's the type of the variable.

Comment: @MartinJames I think it can only return less than the number requested if the socket is non-blocking or there's an error. If it's blocking, it will block until it can send it all.

Comment: @Barmar you may be right.  MSDN and 'man send' don't quite 100% clearly explain the behaviour:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `recv()` loops are requesting more data than you have room in the buffer, because you're not subtracting the bytes you've already read from the limit. You need to do:

```
while ((ret += recv(sock, header, sizeof(t_header) - ret, 0)) >= 0
        && ret < sizeof(t_header))
        ;
```

and:

```
    while ((ret += recv(sock, buff + ret, header->nb_bytes - ret, 0)) >= 0
        && ret < header->nb_bytes)
        ;
```

Also, this looks like it could be a problem:

```
ft_putstr((char*)header);
```

You don't show `ft_putstr()` or the `struct header` definition, but it appears that the function expects a null-terminated string argument, and `header` is not a string.